# Angular JS w/ ui.router - Populate multiple state views with unordered gobbed url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, glob

I'm using ui.router with 5 states, each state nested within the previous state. each state has multiple views for different user types. the only state with url's defined are the first: "" and last: "/:params" so that all the states load into the same window.

Now, since each state is in the window, I want to parse the url params to control the app, without needing a set url model, i.e. i want to take an arbitrary number of unordered params and apply them to each state that has a $stateParams $scoped match down the ancestors.

This way we preserve browser history/bookmarking to match ui-state although never needing to actually navigate elsewhere.

How might this be possible?

```
angular.module('ecoposApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $anchorScrollProvider) {

$stateProvider.
    state('ecoApp', {
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'views/main.html',
        onEnter: function(){
            console.log('ecoApp State');
        },
        onExit: function(){
            console.log('goodbye ecoApp state');
        }
    }).
    state('ecoApp.nav',{

        views:{
            admin:{

                template:'<h2 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Nav Yolo 1</h2>'
            },
            user:{
                template:'<h2 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Nav Yolo 2</h2>'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function(){
            console.log('NAV State');
        },
        onExit: function(){
            console.log('goodbye Navigation state');
        }
    }).
    state('ecoApp.nav.not',{
        views:{
            admin:{
                template:'<h3 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Notifications Yolo 1</h3>'
            },
            user:{
                template:'<h3 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Notifications Yolo 2</h3>'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function(){
            console.log('notifications state');
        },
        onExit: function(){
            console.log('goodbye Notifications state');
        }
    }).
    state('ecoApp.nav.not.tools',{

        views:{
            admin:{
                template: '<h4 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Tools Yolo 1</h4>'
            },
            user:{
                template: '<h4 href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Tools Yolo 2</h4>'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function(){
            console.log('tools state');
        },
        onExit: function(){
            console.log('goodbye tools state');
        }
    }).
    state('ecoApp.nav.not.tools.settings',{
        url:':params',
        views: {
            admin:{
                template:'<a href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Settings Yolo 1</a></div>',
                controller: function(){

                }
            },
            user:{
                template:'<a href ng-click="$state.go(\'^\')">Settings Yolo 2</a></div>'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function(){
            console.log('settings state');
        },
        onExit: function(){
            console.log('goodbye settings state');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In our last state, we have -

```
url:'*path?access_level&preferences'
```

This says the path object on $stateParams can equal anything and to look for access_level and preferences queries such that /settings?access_level=admin&preferences=shop would give this object -

```
$stateParams: {path:settings,access_level:admin,preferences:shop}
```

Then we have in our app's .run fn -

```
$rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
```

Inside the last state's onEnter fn -

```
myService.params.data = $stateParams;
if(/^\/settings(\/.*)?$/.test($stateParams.path)){
    myService.view = 'admin@ecoApp.nav.not.tools.settings';
            }
```

// the data object acts as a state placeholder so that the same object exists even as we switch states.

In our main controller we inject myService - 
$scope.params = myService.params.data;
$scope.myView = myService.params.data.path;

in our main view, we have -

```
<div ui-view="{{myView}}"></div>
```

To finish her off, we go back to our app's .run fn to reload the state on $stateChangeSuccess if the toParams and fromParams are different -

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            if(fromParams !== toParams){
                $state.reload();
                console.log("%c $state reloaded", "background:#aaa; color:#444")
            }
        }
    );
```

So given our url of /settings?access_level=admin&preferences=shop we get myView will = admin@ecoApp.nav.not.tools.settings and can change upon new params with switch/ifs.

Comment: if anyone has trouble following along, lemme know and i'll plunk it up.